# Making a makefile to compile a java project

Tags: java, makefile

I have the following project structure:

```
root
 |--SharedLibrary.jar
 |--Project1
 |   |--package1
 |       |--mainclass.java
 |       |--class1.java
 |   |--package2
 |       |--class2.java
 |   |--Makefile
 |
 |  
 |-Project2
     |- ...
```

I want to write a makefile in `Proyect1` which will compile and execute `mainClass.java` (which depends on all the other classes in the project) using the `sharedLibrary.jar`

I tried writing it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/make
all:
    mkdir output
    javac package1/MainClass.java package1/class1.java package2/class2.java -d output -cp ../sharedLibrary.jar
    java output/package1.MainClass -cp ../sharedLibrary.jar:.

clean:
    rm -r output
```

When I invoke `make` from the console, the first two commands get executed and a directory called output is created with two folders (the two packages) with .class files inside. But the third command, to execute the main class, does not work.

How do I fix it? And since this is my first time making a makefile, are there any good practices I should be following?

Comment: Any reason you're not using a real Java build environment such as Maven or Gradle?  Makefiles are very old technology and not well suited to building Java.

Comment: @JimGarrison I just want to use the most simple tool I can use from console. If Maven / Gradle are better options then I am happy to use them.

Comment: Both Maven and Gradle will require some study and investment of time, but that will pay off in the long run because they do so much more in terms of dependency management than you could ever achieve with makefiles.  Plus, modern IDEs like Eclipse and IntelliJ will do most of the setup for you.

Comment: Try this, java package1.MainClass -cp ../sharedLibrary.jar:.:output/*

Comment: @Santosh `Error: could not find or load main class` For further reference, if I manually enter the `output` folder and run `java package1.MainClass` then I get an exception because it can find the shared library, but it gets to be executed

Comment: I changed a cmd but, hope it works. java package1.MainClass -cp ../sharedLibrary.jar:output/.

Comment: @Santosh No luck :( I'll try again tomorrow, maybe I misstyped something

Comment: Your use of make is unusual. Makefiles are not just scripts that chain commands. They usually define dependencies between targets and pre-requisites such that they are re-built if and only if needed. Anyway, is there a reason why you change the case between your source files and your Makefile (file `mainclass.java` but `MainClass.java` in the Makefile)?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Just a typing mistake

Comment: @JimGarrison is there some kind of introspection needed to build Java successfully? Otherwise I don't see what is behind "old and unsuited".